# Send Mail : Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL does not work

Tags: email, android-intent

I get no error but the mail-to will not be showed ! it stays empty

```
public void Send_Mail(View view) {
        String txt_context = "My comment about the App : \n The App is good but does not support v3";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        intent.setType("message/rfc822"); // 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"receiver@gmail.com"); // **this will not displayed** """
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Comment about the APP");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,txt_context);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old but I encountered the same issue and I found the solution ([in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)):

As explained, `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` is:

> A String[] holding e-mail addresses that should be delivered to.

So to fix your issue, instead of:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"receiver@gmail.com");
```

do:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"receiver@gmail.com"});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you correctly send an email via an intent. The URI arguments are required if not you will have problems getting Gmail to receive your emails.

```
Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("email@gmail.com") + 
          "?subject=" + Uri.encode("the subject") + 
          "&body=" + Uri.encode("the body of the message");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

send.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: your code works, but is there no small edit on my code that it will work without big changing ?

Answer (score 4):

The disadvantage of doing it your way is that it gives gmail issues retrieving the address to send the mail to, and so many apps support `message/rfc822`so your user can get drowned in different clients. I advice you use

```
Intent sendMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
String uriText = "mailto:" + Uri.encode("example@gmail.com") + 
          "?subject=" + Uri.encode("subject") + 
          "&body=" + Uri.encode("body);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);

sendMail.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMail, "Choose a client"));
```

as this is a bit more specific than specifying with `intent.setType("message/rfc822");` and solves the issue with gmail. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

For  kotlin
The emial must be an arrayOf, nos just a string.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("receiber@gmail.com"))
```